# Introducing functional programming constructs in non-functional programming languages

Tags: functional-programming, paradigms

This question has been going through my mind quite a lot lately and since I haven't found a convincing answer to it I would like to know if other users
of this site have thought about it as well.

In the recent years, even though OOP is still the most popular programming paradigm, functional programming is getting a lot of attention. I have only
used OOP languages for my work (C++ and Java) but I am trying to learn some
FP in my free time because I find it very interesting.

So, I started learning Haskell three years ago and Scala last summer. I plan to
learn some SML and Caml as well, and to brush up my (little) knowledge of Scheme. Well, a lot of plans (too ambitious?) but I hope I will find the time
to learn at least the basics of FP during the next few years.
What is important for me is how functional programming works and how / whether
I can use it for some real projects. I have already developed small tools in Haskell.

In spite of my strong interest for FP, I find it difficult to understand why
functional programming constructs are being added to languages like C#, Java, C++, and so on. As a developer interested in FP, I find it more natural to
use, say, Scala or Haskell, instead of waiting for the next FP feature
to be added to my favourite non-FP language.
In other words, why would I want to have only **some** FP in my originally
non-FP language instead of looking for a language that has a better support
for FP?

For example, why should I be interested to have lambdas in Java if I can switch
to Scala where I have much more FP concepts and access all the Java libraries
anyway?
Similarly: why do **some** FP in C# instead of using F# (to my knowledge,
C# and F# can [work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478531/call-f-code-from-c-sharp))?

Java was designed to be OO. Fine. I can do OOP in Java (and I would like to keep using Java in that way). Scala was designed to support OOP + FP. Fine: I can use a mix of OOP and FP in Scala. Haskell was designed for FP: I can do FP in Haskell. If I need to tune the performance of a particular module, I can
interface Haskell with some external routines in C.

But why would I want to do OOP with just **some basic** FP in Java?

So, my main point is: why are non-functional programming languages being extended with **some** functional concept?
Shouldn't it be more comfortable (interesting, exciting, productive) to
program in a language that has been designed from the very beginning to
be functional or multi-paradigm? Don't different programming paradigms
integrate better in a language that was designed for it than in a language
in which one paradigm was only added later?

The first explanation I could think of is that, since FP is a new concept
(it isn't new at all, but it is new for many developers), it needs to be
introduced gradually. However, I remember my switch from imperative to OOP:
when I started to program in C++ (coming from Pascal and C) I really had to
rethink the way in which I was coding, and to do it pretty fast.
It was not gradual. So, this does not seem to be a good explanation to me.

Or can it be that many non-FP programmers are not really interested in
understanding and using functional programming, but they find it practically
convenient to adopt certain **FP-idioms** in their non-FP language?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Just in case (because I have seen several *language wars* on this site):
I mentioned the languages I know better, this question is in no way
meant to start comparisons between different programming
languages to decide which is better / worse.

Also, I am not interested in a comparison of OOP versus FP (pros and cons).
The point I am interested in is to understand why FP is being introduced
one bit at a time into existing languages that were not designed for it
even though there exist languages that were / are specifically designed
to support FP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notwithstanding any specific ideas on the part of language designers, it bears mentioning that authors and stewards of programming languages are, in the end, pushing a product.  So, I might ask why I'd want a camera-phone when my plain phone is a better phone and my camera a better camera, but that isn't going to stop manufacturers of both devices from trying to broaden their product's offering to attract new customers.

Once you look at it from that perspective, then notions of preserving the integrity of the original language become a matter of degrees and tradeoffs.  If I'm the author of OOP language AwesomeCode and I see people starting to get interested in new functional language FCode, do I tell my users "sorry, but this is an OOP language only" and risk them going to C# instead to get at its lambas, or do I cave and grudgingly include some of FCode's functionality?

Comment: +1: Yes, I had also suspected that marketing is sometimes more important than good language design. This would not explain lambdas in C++, though. Also, I understand this from the point of view of a company developing a language. But as a programmer, I would not move from Java to C# because of lambdas but rather to Scala. So, I do not fully understand the attitude of programmers.

Comment: Yes, that does seem hard to account for, though I freely admit to never having done any kind of study as to what motivates programmer adoption of languages (or really to even having considered it). I agree with you that this would be an extremely odd choice, but perhaps people make it.

Comment: Extending C# with FP features means anyone who is already using C# has one less reason to switch. They're not going to get the Haskell crowd to mass-migrate to C#, but it does prevent C# folks from hitting brick walls and causing them to go looking for alternatives.

Comment: @tdammers: Yes, but I wonder if a C# programmer who is happy with very few functional features is really interested in FP or just finds it **cool** because it is the hype of the moment. I sometimes have the impression that **coolness** factors influence language choice more than real practical advantages.

Comment: @Giorgio (and Mr Dietrich) -1 because - C# gains alot as a language from lambdas and their companion LINQ to objects. I feel this answer doesn't really do it justice - it's not just *marketing hype* - it's actually very useful. You start with *it bears mentioning...* but as a standalone answer, it seems a bit off the mark...

Comment: @Max: I admit I have a very skeptical opinion towards the whole development C#, C++ and Java are undergoing, and the addition of small pieces of FP is part of my problem with it. I do not doubt that lambdas are useful in C#, but wouldn't it be more coherent to push a language that already has lambdas (e.g. F#) instead of extending C#? From a programming language design point of view it would, from a marketing point of view (how many programmers will follow?) it would not. So I agree that introducing lambdas in C# and Java has a lot to do with marketing.

Comment: @Giorgio It has to do with using the tool that is best for the job. For some jobs having functions as first-class citizens is very good - such as transforming a sequence. Being able to utilize that in C# without going for F# full stop is much better because then you wouldn't be able to utilize what C# does better (without a lot of effort, as you need to separate into different assemblies - and that's something Haskell and C++ cannot do for example). IMO purity is not an example of good language design - having a rich toolset is. But opinions will differ unto the end of time. :)

Comment: @Max: "But opinions will differ unto the end of time.": The purpose of my question was namely to understand how other programmers evaluate the languages they choose. I do not defend purity at all costs and I think multi-paradigm is OK, but I also give great importance to stability (learn once) and design coherence because I find it more difficult to use a heterogeneous language. I prefer to have a rich tool set in the form of a rich library. But yes, every programmer has a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at LINQ - it would not be possible without those *some*  FP features, whereas it hides all the scary FP stuff under the bonnet.

FP features are very useful for those who implement somewhat complicated libraries and frameworks - it is unreasonable to use a different language for such things. "*End users*", all the average enterprisey programmers, won't need to know anything about that arcane features, but they're happy to use the libraries built upon FP extensions.

Comment: This is an interesting point. Maybe there is also a lot of **scary** OOP stuff that did not make it into mainstream programming languages because was it was not considered useful enough (see e.g. the comment about using only single-dispatch in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/59387/is-oop-hard-because-it-is-not-natural).

Comment: On the other hand, I would not justify FP features because they allow to implement libraries: why would it be unreasonable to use a separate programming language? There is separate compilation for that. Why not implement the library in F# and use it from C#?

Comment: For example, isn't the Python sort() built-in function normally implemented in C?

Comment: @Giorgio, another programming language often means using another (or additional) set of runtime libraries. Not everyone ready to carry this burden (e.g., `scala-library.jar`). Python and C is a different thing - Python interpreter depends on C standard library anyway.

Comment: Extending the language and the compiler is also a burden (additional complexity, possibly slower compilation). I am not sure if one of the two approaches has a clear advantage.

Comment: @Giorgio, normally you do not pay for things you do not use. And, having the FP stuff in a core of your compiler might actually significantly simplify it.

Comment: "Normally you do not pay for things you do not use": you mean if I do not use the language extensions? True, if I work alone I have this choice. If I work in a team I will sooner or later have to master the whole language the team is using (code reviews, bug fixing, and so on).

Comment: @Giorgio, there must be a separation of labour anyway. And I actually meant that if you're not using a feature, you won't have any compilation overhead associated with it.

Comment: "there must be a separation of labour anyway. And I actually meant that if you're not using a feature, you won't have any compilation overhead associated with it." Saving compilation time is one aspect. From my experience working in a team, each programmer will sooner or later have to work on code that has been written by others. This means that even if I am not interested in certain language features, I will probably have to learn them because other team members use them. In this sense, I think that a minimalistic programming language is better suited for team work.

Comment: @Giorgio, you know, there is an inline assembly available in most of the C++ compilers. Now, when did you have to maintain a C++ code written by one of your colleagues which relied heavily on an inline assembly? It's an arcane feature which is always well hidden within the libraries, far away from end users. Same should be true for the arcane FP features in the modern mainstream languages. LINQ for the users, FP for the LINQ implementors. But, on the other hand, I'd personally prefer to stay away from working with underqualified teams.

Comment: I would not consider a developer underqualified if they use only a subset of a language that is too rich: often this is a conscious decision because one wants to concentrate on solving problem, not on learning new language features that are almost equivalent to features they already use. You can see it as an application of the KISS / YAGNI principles.

Comment: @Giorgio, learning language features is cheap. Not learning and not using them is expensive. I'd consider a programmer severely underqualified, if he is not aware of all the major paradigms and language design principles and if he cannot pick up a new language in a couple of hours. But of course you're right - no language should introduce features which are "almost equivalent" to the already existing features. But if a feature can save a dozen of boilerplate lines, it must be used.

Comment: "If a feature can save a dozen of boilerplate lines, it must be used.": I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Purely functional programming styles have serious problems with input/output. That's why most functional languages are not pure and Haskell which is has...intimidating I/O techniques. Anything that requires a destructive update like Graphics for instance is harder to do that in functional languages.

Functional constructs are being added to mainstream languages for three main reasons:

1. Pattern Matching: Functional languages typically have extremely compact syntax for dealing with pattern matching. Python has shades of this with its for statements. This winds up very useful in things like Data Mining.
2. Generic Programming/Metaprogramming: These both improve code adaptability tremendously by allowing a program to either be more flexible or to modify itself as it goes along. This can be hugely important in AI.
3. State Control: Functional Programming has no variables whatsoever, it has symbols instead. Every "variable" has a single unchanging value. That means we don't get any kind of ambiguity in terms of what something is. A magic A is a magic A while in imperative languages it could be a Magic A or B or C or D or whatever. There is no chance at all for an undetermined state in Functional Programming because there aren't any states in that sense. What is done instead is the idea of isolation of I/O. You get back what you put in, not some random weirdness and due to isolation there is no way that I/O can corrupt your internal program (ideally). This whole mess comes in hand in particular with Concurrency as you don't need locks or barriers.

I'd argue that Object Oriented Programming is still fully applicable with Functional Programming. OO Programming is a useful way of organizing and structuring code while Functional Programming is a useful way of ordering and structuring computation. OCAML is a prime example here. OO Programming has even been combined with logic programming in the form of Prolog++. So OO Programming can certainly benefit from other styles just as much as they can benefit from it.

Comment: My point is why use, say, C++ with **some** FP instead of using, say, OCAML? Is OCAML not suitable for the kinds of application C++ is used for? Are C++ programmer too lazy to learn something different? Is OCAML too FP-oriented? Other reasons?

Comment: Actually, I find libcairo, for example, much easier to use in Haskell than in C. In C, you have to drag the Cairo context around explicitly, and you have to be careful about when you can and cannot access it; in Haskell, you explicitly do all your rendering in a `Render` monad context, and you never have to worry about accidentally trying to render to a dangling surface pointer or something.

Comment: "Purely functional programming styles have serious problems with input/output.": I was not arguing about pros and cons of FP and whether one should use pure FP or a mix of OOP + FP. My point is "adding some FP support to an OOP language" versus "designing an OOP + FP language from scratch".

Comment: "Purely functional programming styles have serious problems with input/output.": This idea keeps many programmers away from FP, but AFAIK it is not true, or can you back it with some example?

Comment: "Haskell which is has...intimidating I/O techniques" -- Haskell does not have intimidating IO techniques.  You should try learning Miranda, the language it replaced, which had *non-referentially-transparent IO in a language whose interpreter assumed referential transparency*, which made for some entertaining (hopefully theoretical) possibilities...

Comment: I don't get the idea that IO in haskell is hard or complicated. No, when you see your first `main = do { putStrLn "What's your name?"; name <- getLine; putStrLn $ "Hi there, " ++ name"; }` you won't realize and learn all about monadic binding and type classes and so on, but the first time you see the equivalent Java code you won't know what in/output streams and buffers and tokens and scanners and classes and static methods are either, so I think it's really unfair to compare like that.

Answer (score 1):

Erik's answer is correct for the "why" this is done.

I'd like to add that when selecting a language, pick the one that naturally supports the paradigm.  For example, wanting to do FP and picking C++ and wrangling in some strange libraries is inferior in every way to just picking a FP language to start with.  Pick the tool that best meets the need.  If you really want FP features, use an FP language, don't use the weak half-functional implementation of it with leaky abstractions in another language.

This kind of thing annoys me when people try to wrangle everything into The One True Language, which is the wrong idea.  Use different tools for different jobs, don't try to make the ultimate Swiss army knife which doesn't really do any job well.

Comment: +1: "Use different tools for different jobs, don't try to make the ultimate Swiss army knife which doesn't really do any job well"! I think you pointed out two good explanations: (1) companies do not want to change too much the language they sell because of marketing reasons, (2) some developers want to have some FP in their favourite language because they do not want to learn something too different (from the One True Language they already know).

Answer (score 0):

Who's to say that multiple paradigms can't coexist?  There are number of hybrid languages that bridge the gap between OOP and FP like F# and Scala.

The trouble is the last couple decades made OOP the industry standard and so the majority of folks in the industry understand designing software with objects.  FP offers some low-hanging fruit (ideas such as LINQ) that can be immediately useful in the OO world.  By offering the low-hanging fruit first, programmers can remain productive and gradually cross the bridge, learning to apply FP ideas at their own pace.  This gradual induction into the FP paradigm would not be possible if programmers were forced to embrace the entire paradigm all at once -- e.g. dive straight into Haskell.

Comment: I am in favour of approaches like Scala (I do not know F#, probably it is similar) in which a language is designed from scratch to integrate both paradigms. In other cases the FP features are not well integrated and lead, IMHO, to artificial solutions that would not be idiomatic in FP. For example, I remember an article on how to use lambdas in language X (lambda were added to this language only lately): it was a situation in which a for loop would have perfectly done the job, but the loop's body had been replaced by a large lambda expression. In FP I'd rather have used `map` or `reduce`.